# Trouble Painting Vertices with Fill Brush

Tags: vertices, texture-painting

I'm new to Blender. I am trying to paint on a 3d imported OBJ via the vertices in my UV unwrap. I am able to paint just fine freehand, but I wanted to also be able to select vertices in "Edit Mode" and use the fill brush to fill those in.  I've followed people's instructions online for how to do this, but it does not seem to work for me. I took screenshots of my selected vertices in Edit Mode and then my screens when my 3D View is in Texture Paint mode and my UV Editor is in Mask Mode. I am clicking on my same selected vertices on my UV Editor and nothing is happening. Any insight on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!
[image]
[image]

Comment: I wanted to add that in my bottom picture, I know "Face selection masking for painting" is disabled. It does not work when it is enabled, either.

Comment: Have you tried going into face selection mode, enable the face selection masking, and then using another brush other than your fill? Also, have you looked at the Options panel in Texture Paint Mode and checked to see if you have toggled Cavity mask by accident? Typical way i do this is 1. select faces in edit mode 2. enter texture paint mode and enable face selection masking 3. paint with the fill brush in mix mode